# Растягивание элемента с помощью resizable() за пределы родительского блока

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, плагин

Есть код HTML:

```
<div class="grid_12 submenu center">
    <div id="beards_1" class="beards accessories"></div>
    <div id="beards_2" class="beards accessories"></div>
    <div id="beards_3" class="beards accessories"></div>
    <div id="beards_4" class="beards accessories"></div>
</div>
```

и код jQuiery:

```
$(".accessories").click(function() {
   $(this).css("border","1px solid red"), $(this).resizable();
}
```

Вместе с увеличение `div.accessories` увеличивается и `div` с классом `.grid_12 submenu center`. Как это предотвратить?